# shell create new folder

Tags: bash, shell

I have many files' path, but I need to copy all files into other location `/sample`, and I want to copy files into different folders:

```
/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz
/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_2.fq.gz
/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/clean_111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz.total.info
```

I want to copy those files into AS34_59329 folder inside `/sample`

```
/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59328/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz
/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59328/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_2.fq.gz
/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59328/clean_111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz.total.info
```

I want to copy those file into AS34_59328 folder inside `/sample`

I write codes to scp all file into /sample folder, but I don't know how to put each files into different sub-directory, like:

```
/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59328/clean_111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz.total.info
```

put into AS34_59328

```
  #! /bin/bash
   while read myline  
    do  
     for i in $myline
        do 
        if [ -f $i]; then
              #how to put different files into different sub-directory
              scp -r $i xxx@191.168.174.43:/sample
        fi
        done
    done < data.list
```

new changed part

```
      #! /bin/bash
      while read myline
      do
            for i in $myline
            do
              if [ -f $i ]
              then
              relname=$(echo $i | sed 's%\(/[^/][^/]*\)\{5\}/%%')
              echo $relname
              fi
            done
      done < /home/jesse/T11073_all_3254.fq.list
```

Comment: With which part of the solution are you stuck? Identifying the files to copy? Generating the new directory name? Making the new directory? Copying the files? If you show us what you've done so far, it's a lot easier for us to help you!

Comment: thanks, making the new directory, put each files into different sub-directory

Comment: In other words, "all of it".

Comment: Can you share your script so far so that we can help you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you need to strip the leading 5 components of the pathname off the filename.  Since you don't have spaces in your names (the way you're using `for i in $myline` precludes that possibility), you can use:

```
#! /bin/bash
while read myline  
do  
    for i in $myline
    do 
        if [ -f $i ]
        then
            relname=$(echo $i | sed 's%\(/[^/][^/]*\)\{5\}/%%')
            scp -r $i xxx@191.168.174.43:/sample/$relname
        fi
    done
done < data.list
```

The regex is just a way of looking for a sequence of five sets of slash followed by one or more non-slashes plus one more slash and deleting them.  Since slashes figure prominently in the search, I used `%` to mark the sections of the `s///` operation instead.

For example, given the input:

```
/a/b/c/d/e/f/g
```

the output from the `sed` is:

```
f/g
```

Note that this code does not explicitly create directories on the remote machine; it just specifies where the file is to go.  If you need to create them too, you will have to investigate `ssh`, probably, to run `mkdir -p /sample/$(dirname $relname)` on the remote machine (where the dirname operation can be run either locally or remotely).

Note that `scp` has a recursive copy mode (`-r`) which would simplify things considerably if you knew you needed to copy all the files from the local directory to the remote.

Comment: Too much copy'n'paste — I copied your code and didn't spot, much less fix, the bug in it!  `if [ -f $i]` needs a space between `$i` and `]`, triggering the error.

Comment: changed it, but it can't show anything. i have already attach changed code,hope you can see it.

Comment: It probably means that the file names you're testing with don't exist after all — that is, the `if [ -f $i ]` test is failing to find the file, and therefore not running the `sed` or `echo` commands.  I tried out a copy of your script, and ran into exactly that problem.  When I specified a name that existed, the test worked fine.  You do know about `sh -x script` (or `bash -x script`) to debug scripts, don't you?

Comment: thanks,for create directories, since the file has many lines it will create many directories. so if i add ssh mkdir -p /sample/$relname in for loop. it can work?

Comment: I try your code, but it seems wrong, it print Fq/AS39_59324/120225_I171_FCD0L8CACXX_L2_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz for the relname, but i need is AS39_59324 for the directory name

Comment: Your call.  Drop the file name at the end if you like.  You probably know enough shell to be able to do that (and if you don't, `man dirname` would help, though `bash` has other techniques that can be found by reading its manual, especially under Parameter Expansion).  If you're making directories, it is crucial that you drop the file names...so I made a mitsake in describing the `mkdir -p` command; I'll fix that.